# PHP/Regex. Capture all but last of .*

Tags: php, regex

So I have the following regex: `(.*)`

However, I need to capture the whole thing EXCEPT the last character.

*It might seem as if doing a `substr(-1` on the result will solve it... however this is impossible because of the context in which this is done. It will only be confusing to explain why.*

Comment: is `(.*)` the whole of your expression, or is it part of a larger expression?

Comment: `(.*)` can match a zero-length string. What is "all but last" in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a following character :

```
(.*).
```